# How to pass multiple parameters from javascript function to controller

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, jquery

I know that we can send multiple parameters by specifying them "," separated but what if count of parameters is dynamic.Below code works fine for specific amount of parameters. How can I accomplish sending of multiple parameters whose count can be varied ?

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Home/xxx',             
            data: { "FirstName": FirstName, "LastName": LastName,"InputNo3": InputNo3, "InputNo4": InputNo4, "InputNo5": InputNo5 }
        }).done(function (msg) {
            $(".popup").html(msg);
            $(".background").show();
        });
```

Comment: Are parameters are countable at all? If you know all possible variants, then you can make Model with these parameters, and use it on MVC side

Comment: @Sergey: thanks, Yes I can get the count from DB. Could you redirect me to any resource ?

Comment: Array is definitely way to go, but it types are different for these parameters, then you need to make List<object> that won't be useful at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case if parameters are dynamic, and you don't know what are they, then you can use a dictionary as Model. Here is a sample on Scott's blog - http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Backend code:

```
public ActionResult Blah(IDictionary<string, string> parameters) {
    if (parameters.ContainsKey("FirstName"))
    {
        var firstNameValue = parameters["FirstName"];
        // do something with it
    }
}
```

JavasScipt code:

```
var objData = [];
objData[0].Key = "FirstName";
objData[0].Value = FirstName;
objData[1].Key = "LastName";
objData[1].Value = LastName;
objData[2].Key = "InputNo3";
objData[2].Value = InputNo3Value;
// populate other needed properties


$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'Home/xxx',             
    data: objData
}).done(function (msg) {
    $(".popup").html(msg);
    $(".background").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have many parameters with different type like string, int, object, better you can add it into `object` and send it.

```
var myComplextObject={};
myComplextObject.FirstName='';
myComplextObject.Age=27;
myComplextObject.Address={};
myComplextObject.Address.City='Chennai';

//etc
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'Home/xxx',             
        data: myComplextObject
    }).done(function (msg) {
        $(".popup").html(msg);
        $(".background").show();
    });
```